# Xpath get data if conditions is satisfied in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to extract data.
There are thousands of product which i am scraping 
The problem is the data on these pages is not consistent
ie.

```
<table class="c999 fs12 mt10 f-bold">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td width="16%">Type</td>
                            <td class="c222">Kurta</td>
                        </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                <td>Fabric</td>
                                <td class="c222">Cotton</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                    <tr>
                                <td>Sleeves</td>
                                <td class="c222">3/4th Sleeves</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                    <tr>
                                <td>Neck</td>
                                <td class="c222">Mandarin Collar</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                    <tr>
                                <td>Wash Care</td>
                                <td class="c222">Gentle Wash</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                    <tr>
                                <td>Fit</td>
                                <td class="c222">Regular</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                    <tr>
                                <td>Length</td>
                                <td class="c222">Knee Length</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                                        <tr>
                                <td>Color</td>
                                <td class="c222">Brown</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                    <tr>
                                <td>Fabric Details</td>
                                <td class="c222">Cotton</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                Style                            </td>
                            <td class="c222"> Printed</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            SKU                        </td>
                        <td id="qa-sku" class="c222"> SR227WA70ROJINDFAS</td>
                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                        <td></td>

                    </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
```

So these rows are not consistent .
Sometimes the "Type" is at first position and sometimes it is at second.
I wrote the code to loop through the values and compare the value of 1st td if it is "Type" the get the value of its corresponding td but it is not working
Here is the code.

```
table_data = response.xpath('//*[@id="productInfo"]/table/tr')
        for data in table_data:
            name = data.xpath('td/text()').extract()
```

What should i do??

Comment: Plese provide the url of this page? or what should be the possible output you want to get from this page ?

Comment: Can u come to the discussion

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following xpath :

```
name = data.xpath("td[position()=(count(../../tr/td[.='Type']/preceding-sibling::td)+1)]/text()").extract()
```

Above xpath filters `<td>` by position, returning only `<td>` in position equal to position of `<td>Type</td>`. Getting position of `<td>Type</td>` done by counting number of it's preceding sibling `<td>` plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
In [29]: response.xpath('//table[@class="c999 fs12 mt10 f-bold"]/tr[contains(td/text(), "Type")]/td[contains(text(), "Type")]/following-sibling::td/text()|//table[@class="c999 fs12 mt10 f-bold"]/tr[contains(td/text(), "Type")]/td[contains(text(), "Type")]/preceding-sibling::td/text()').extract()
Out[29]: [u'Kurta']
```

no matter whether `td` is coming after `Type` or before `Type`, This will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get sibling node of `td` containing string 'Type' no matter what is position of this `td` you can try following xpath:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Type')]/following-sibling::td/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[.="Fabric"]/../td[2]/text()
```

Did it with the above code